# Store the uploaded .txt file with newlines in a variable Django

Tags: python, django, post, file-io

I wanted to store the content of an uploaded .txt file **(with newlines)** in a variable, so that I could call my other functions on that variable. But I can not find a way to achieve this. I tried all the methods, but it doesn't work

Here is the simple code example:
**Template**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="txt">
    <button type="submit" name="encode">Encode</button>
</form>
```

**View**

```
from .algorithms.algo import encoder 

def encoder(request):
    context = {'encoded':''}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.FILES['txt'].read()
        encoded = encoder(text)
        context['encoded'] = encoded
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Also, when I tried to output the file, it showed me some strange text instead of the actual content of the file.

Please admins don't close this question, I've surfed all over the internet, but didn't find the answer for my question

---

Or is there a way to get the value from `textarea`, and store it in a variable with newlines?

Comment: provide your strange text here

Comment: @AshrafulIslam b'\r\n\r\n48' but actually it should be '\n\n48' (with only two newlines). Anyway, when I store this data in a variable and continue to execute my function(even with this strange data), it returns the wrong answer. It seems like, content is stored in a different format. I outputed it in template.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
text.decode("utf-8")
```

or

```
encoded.decode("utf-8")
```

before contexting the value

Comment: It removed those weird dashes, but it looks like it converted all newlines to spaces or something. =(

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the content first because the data you are reading is in bytes. You can do this by changing:

`text = request.FILES['txt'].read()` to `text = request.FILES['txt'].read().decode()`

or you can decode it after with:

`text = text.decode()`

Comment: It doesn't store the newlines, but yes it clears the text